# primefaces mobile autocomplete

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-mobile

I am trying to implement autocomplete in primefaces mobile. I've made the test for primefaces, it works fine, under *hypothesis* autocompletion in primefaces mobile has the same underlying principals as that of primefaces, here's the code that should do the trick :

```
<h:form>
        <p:autoComplete  completeMethod="#{someBean.complete}"/>
</h:form>
```

I am using primefaces mobile 0.9.4, in the [mobile showcases](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/mobile/showcase.jsf) they have `PrimeFacesMobile-0.9.5-SNAPSHOT` (which I can't download from [here](http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html)).

Is Autocomplete unusable in the my current version (`primefaces-mobile-0.9.4`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the SNAPSHOT version that you've mentionned, here's the link for the jar : http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces-mobile/0.9.5-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: That works, but I believe working with a snapshot version is dangereous. Thanks anyways !